# How to write parser rules for localized number formats?

Tags: antlr4

How can I write an Antlr (v4) grammar that correctly parses floating point numbers when the decimal and thousands separators (decimal grouping char) are dependent on the locale calling system?

Currently I try to swap the characters in the input string before passing to the parser, and while this works it feels like a hack. Is there no way to make a "parametrized" parser, where some things can be passed as arguments, such as the char values of these tokens?

Comment: Could you write your number-recognizing code to catch both situations, and then raise a "wrong kind of number for current locale" error sometime later? Another possibility is to use [grammar imports](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Grammar+Structure#GrammarStructure-GrammarImports) so that you can have an "English" grammar and then a "Euro" grammar which subtly tweaks it, and pick the right one to invoke at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Parser and lexer construction algorithms usually assume that the alphabet is fixed rather than variable. This is a very helpful assumption when preparing runtime decisions at construction time, and veryfing that a language definition is unambiguous.

Note that localized numbers could likely cause ambiguities when embedded in a more complex context. E.g. in German, a comma is used instead of a decimal point, but numbers written like this can hardly be grouped in comma-separated lists.

For decomposing single numeric values, separate lexers/parsers could be used for each localization variant, or multiple alternatives could be supported in a single language definition.